# Dynamic hero-image sizing in CSS

Tags: html, css

I was recently browsing [Quanta Magazine](https://www.quantamagazine.org/) and noticed that the hero image had a nice effect where it would shrink in size as the screen got smaller. I looked into the CSS to try to figure out how this was happening, but I couldn't determine what was causing this:

[image]

I was hoping someone could point me to the right piece of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

They used

`.ThisBackgroundImage { width: 100%; height: auto; }`

in their code

more on it:

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp

Answer (score 0):

Here i think they are using padding hack.[image]